# Is it possible to get GPS data from AR.Drone with Flight Recorder in ardrone_autonomy?

Tags: ros, gps, mavlink, ardrone-autonomy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using AR.Drone with Flight Recorder (witch enable geolocation using the GPS module).

I installed ardrone_autonomy and very pleased with it.
But there is no GPS data in topics published.

However, using QGroundControl, I can connect to AR.Drone and get GPS data in GLOBAL_POSITION_INT packet, so I can get GPS data in my program with MAVLINK.

The problem is that I can't use ardrone_autonomy and MAVLINK connection simultaniously.
When I start ardrone_autonomy, I loose connection in QGroundControl (MAVLINK).

So my question is about possibility of reading GPS data from AR.Drone with ardrone_autonomy or using ardrone_autonomy simultaniously with MAVLINK connection?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/127996/is-it-possible-to-get-gps-data-from-ar.drone-with-flight-recorder-in-ardrone_autonomy?/) by [Rr](https://answers.ros.org/users/2748/rr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As both @jjwiseman and @jcerruti mentioned, there is experimental support for GPS through "Parrot Flight Recorder" peripheral in ardrone_autonomy driver. It publishes data received from GPS and exposes a service to do GPS based waypoint navigation on-board. [GPS Support](http://ardrone-autonomy.readthedocs.org/en/gps-waypoint/gps.html) section of [gps-waypoint branch documentation](http://ardrone-autonomy.readthedocs.org/en/gps-waypoint/) provides more information.

**Update:** GPS support was added to the driver by patching the official SDK. Therefor, it's possible to trigger on-board GPS based waypoint navigation with the driver while simultaneously access video footage over Wifi.

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2015-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some quick research suggests that this isn't possible with the existing drivers:

- ardrone_autonomy is built on the ardrone SDK, which doesn't appear to support the new GPS module. Probably a dead end.
- [roscopter](https://github.com/epsilonorion/roscopter/wiki) and [mavlink_ros](https://github.com/mavlink/mavlink_ros) are based on the mavlink libraries and communication protocol which supports the GPS, but only appear to support communication over a serial port. You could probably extend this to support IP communication to support the AR.Drone.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jjwiseman](https://answers.ros.org/users/1918/jjwiseman/) on 2014-05-06**:
It looks like support for GPS is being added to ardrone_autonomy.  See https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy/pull/95 and https://github.com/AutonomyLab/ardrone_autonomy/tree/gps

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2015-05-23**:
Please check my answer about GPS support with the official SDK.